# Admin 2 restricted access

Tags: windows

On my Remote window server, I want to create one additional administrator a/c, However this second administrator should not have the Privilege to modify Firewall setting, is this Possible?

However apart from this right he should have Full access to the remote window server, also he should not be able to change the password.

Is there way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

No. If the user is a member of the Administrators group, that user can do whatever they want. Any changes you make to prevent access to the firewall settings or prevent the password from being changed can be undone by that user.

Comment: But my Previous server company has done that, But now they are not telling how to do it since we have changed the server company.

Comment: I stand by my answer. Either you did actually have Administrator rights and the blocks they put it were simply cosmetic and easily bypassed, or they just gave you additional permissions to do what you needed to do and not actual Administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really need the account to be member of the administrator group, then the proper way to implement this type of delegation of duty is to place the machine behind a separate firewall system and use a different set of credentials to manage that device.

Another solution would be to use a regular user account and grant it the rights needed for doing whatever needs to be done.

Unfortunately, it isn't always possible to implement either of these. In this case, I suggest that you describe the actual problem you want to solve (instead of the issue you're having with a solution you already chose) and see if someone can offer some advise.

Comment: Actually i want that codes should be developed only on window server, but I also don't want that codes should go out of server. so firewall will be set one way things can be downloaded but nothing should go out of the server.

Comment: If you're worried about people taking your intellectual property the answer isn't technical roadblocks (which can always be bypassed) but to hire trustworthy people and pay them well.